# Установка nodejs на OpenServer (Windows)

Tags: node.js, установка

Всем привет!
Скачал с оф.сайта node.js, установил по такому пути: E:\OpenServer\nodejs , создал текстовой файл path.txt в openServer (...\userdata\config), прописал в текстовом файле путь до node.js E:\OpenServer\nodejs, перезапускаю OpenServer и не работает node.js . Что не так делаю?
В настройках OpenServer, в разделе "Сервер" сменил переменную path на Свой Path + userdata/config/path.txt + Win Path
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в виндовый PATH прописали путь до npm?

Comment: В виндовый PATH, честно говоря, не знаю как прописать путь до npm. Но, если открывать консоль Node без вирт.сервера OpenServer - всё работает нормально. Нужно просто интергрировать  в OpenServer Node.js

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно выполнить эти простые шаги для установки Node.js (npm - это часть node.js) на OpenServer

### **1. Установка NodeJS**

Перейти на сайт https://nodejs.org/ и скачайте версию "Recommended For Most Users".
Устанавливаем NodeJS как обычную программу для Windows

---

### **2. Добавление NodeJS в OpenServer**

- откройте НАСТРОЙКИ OpenServer
- перейдите на вкладку СЕРВЕР
- в "настройка использования переменной Path" выбрать из выпадающего списка "Свой Path + userdata/config/path.txt + Win Path"
- СОХРАНИТЕ изменения

---

### **3. Создание файла path.txt**

в паке OpenServer-а находим заходим в *\userdata\config* создаем файл path.txt

Откройте созданный файл path.txt и добавьте в него путь до nodejs. У меня это "*C:\Program Files\nodejs*"

Сохраните изменения в файле и чтоб openserver смог подхватить nodejs, то обязательно нужно **ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗИТЬ OPEN-SERVER**

---

### **4. Проверка**

Откройте консоль OpenServer и напишите `node -v` или `npm -v`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы увидели версию - поздравляю!
Если нет - убедитесь что все настройки сохранены и перезапустите сервер еще раз

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так: Устанавливай обычно на Windows node.js (версия LTS).

1) открой командную строку Windows и напиши npn -v  Если увидишь версию например: 6.4.1 значит все работает.

2) Теперь настроим добавление NodeJS в консоль СonEmu - те Openserver:

```
 настройки/Сервер: и смотришь в окошке "настройка использования переменной Path": выбираешь: Свой Path + Win Path
```

3) в любой директории должна работать: npn -v  == (твоя версия) например 6.4.1

удачи в разработке :)